# Binary search in java

Tags: java, arrays, search, binary

I am trying to implement a binary search in Java, doesn't work... don't know why, It always gives me an error saying the number wasn't found...

I am not sure why, I'm not seeing any error :S thanks for your help...

```
public void busquedaBinaria(int[] arreglo, int buscar) {        

        int centro = 0; //middle
        int inferior = 0;
        int superior = arreglo.length - 1;
        boolean encontrado = false; //found flag

        while(inferior <= superior)
        {
            centro = (superior + inferior) / 2;            

              if (arreglo[centro] == buscar){
                  System.out.println("-Number " + buscar + " found in the " + centro + " position.");
                  encontrado=true;
                  break;
              }
              else if (arreglo[centro] > buscar) {
                  superior = centro - 1;
              }
              else{
                  inferior = centro + 1;
              }     
              System.out.println(centro);
        }

        if (encontrado == false) {
            System.out.println("-Number " + buscar + " hasn't been found.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the values that you pass to the method?

Comment: The code appears correct. Make sure that `arreglo` is sorted in ascending order. If if is not, that would explain the behavior you see.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Arrays#binarySearch` or `Collections#binarySearch`, which are already available in library.

Comment: @PaulDinh  Maybe the OP can clarify.

Comment: This answer is out of scope, the goal is to exercise, to learn fundamental algorithms, not to realize a program.

Answer (score 1):

Binary Search will only work with the sorted numbers. Please make sure that the array **arreglo** is sorted.

If your array is in Descending order then you have to change your logic a littel bit.

```
     if (arreglo[centro] == buscar){
       System.out.println("-Number " + buscar + " found in the " + centro + " position.");
       encontrado=true;   
       break; 
     } 
     else if (arreglo[centro] > buscar) { 
       superior = centro + 1;
     }
     else{ 
       inferior = centro - 1; 
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my contribution:

```
public class BinarySearch
{
   private static String search( String[] entries, String entry, int left, int right )
   {
      int index = ( left + right ) / 2;
      if( left > right || index >= entries.length )
      {
         return null;
      }
      int cmp   = entries[index].compareTo( entry );
      if( cmp == 0 )
      {
         return entry;
      }
      if( cmp > 0 )
      {
         return search( entries, entry, left, index - 1 );
      }
      return search( entries, entry, index + 1, right );
   }// String search( String[] entries, String entry, int left, int right )



   public static String search( String[] entries, String entry )
   {
      return search( entries, entry, 0, entries.length );
   }// String search( String[] entries, String entry )



   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      String[] entries = new String[] { "Aubin", "Barbara", "George", "Muriel", "Sarah", "Tom" };
      for( String entry : entries )
      {
         System.out.println( search( entries, entry ));
      }
      System.out.println( search( entries, "Toto" ));
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
package Lab; //package
                   
public class BinarySearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; 
        int beg=0, end=arr.length-1, mid = (beg+end)/2,item =10;
        while(beg<=end && arr[mid] !=item)
        {
            if(item>arr[mid]) beg=mid+1;

             else if (item<arr[mid]) end=mid-1;

            mid = (beg+end)/2;
        }
        if(item==arr[mid])
            System.out.println("Item foudn at indes"+mid);
        else 
            System.out.println("Item not found");
        
    }
}
```